# Using Process.Start() with IE and waiting for web response

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, process

Is there a way to capture a response from the Process class using it to launch Internet Explorer.

```
Process proc = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe",
            Arguments = "http://www.google.com",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        }
    };
    proc.Start();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    proc.Kill();
```

I tried :

```
 while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream) {
 string line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
// do something with line
}
```

but IE sends back an immediate response of hey, i opened and called the URL. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If IE doesn't volunteer the information itself through the console, it will probably be hard for you to get to.

Comment: Does IE even write anything to any of the std streams? Anyways you could try Process.OutputDataReceived

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of getting information from IE when it is running in a separate process.

However, you can run it inside of a [Web Browser control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your own `Form`.  IE then exposes a number of [events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser_events(v=vs.110).aspx) that you can listen to.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but im calling 11 concurrently and it slows down dramatically. I may consider this option but it is within a service with no form. The webclient refused to cooperate so I'm trying other options.